# Coset representatives in the quotient of ring of integers

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K= \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ where $d$ is a square free negative integer that is either $2$ or $3$  $\mod 4$. (So $\mathcal{O}_K= \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$). I proved a theorem as below:

Let $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ an integral ideal. Then there exist $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ such that $\mathfrak{a}=a\mathbb{Z} +(b+c\sqrt{d})\mathbb{Z}$.

In this setup, $a$ is the smallest possible positive integer in the ideal and similarly $c$ is the smallest positive integer such that $b+c\sqrt{d} $ is in the ideal.

Now, I have a problem with the lemma below:

Let we have $\mathfrak{a}=a\mathbb{Z} +(b+c\sqrt{d})\mathbb{Z}$ and consider $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{a}$. Then coset representatives are given as $\{x+y\sqrt{d}: 0 \le x < a, 0\le y < c \}$
.

I do not understand that part. For example, maybe we have some elements in this set so that they belong the same ideal  class. How do we guarantee  that these are the all representatives?

Comment: This should just follow as in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133495/coset-representatives-for-mathcalo-k-alpha?rq=1).