# Quotient of Gaussian Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was given to prove that $\frac{Z[i]}{<a+ib>}$ $\cong$ $\frac{Z}{<a^2+b^2>}$ , when gcd(a,b) = 1.

I am using the mapping f: Z $\to$ $\frac{Z[i]}{<a+ib>}$ given by f(x)=x+< a+ib >.
I have proved that the homomorphism is onto. But I am not being able to show that ker f = < $a^2+b^2$ >. If x $\in$ ker f , then a+ib |x . hence a-ib | x. thus $ a^2+b^2$ | $x^2$. From here how can I conclude that $a^2+b^2$ |x ? Please give some hint. Thank you.

Comment: A lot of useful material for you [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23358/11619). Not closing as a dupe yet. And also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52537/11619).

Comment: **Hint** $ $ Rationalize the denominator of $\,x/(a+bi).\,$ If you get stuck see the linked dupe.

Comment: See also [this way.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133495/242) and see [this special case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374203/242) for motivation.